# Apply parameter's nullability to return value

Tags: java, nullable, findbugs

I have a method that is declared to both accept and return `null`.

```
@CheckForNull
public static String truncate(@CheckForNull text, int maxLength) { ... }
```

It returns `null` only if `text` is `null`. When I pass in the return value from a method marked `@Nonnull`, FindBugs has no way to know that `truncate` will not return `null` and thus issues a warning if I assign it to a field marked `@Nonnull`.

```
@Nonnull
public static String trimmedOrEmptyIfNull(@CheckForNull text) { ... }
...
@Nonnull
private String message;
...
message = truncate(trimmedOrEmptyIfNull(e.getMessage()), 100);
```

The warning here is a false positive because `trimmedOrEmptyIfNull` is marked as `@Nonnull` and thus `truncate` will return a non-null value and could be inferred as `@Nonnull` itself.

Is there a way to make FindBugs aware of this connection between the nullability of the return value and the parameter?

Comment: This is one of the many reasons I'm not convinced that nullability annotations will ever be feasible.

Comment: jspecifiy allows something like this `<T extends @Nullable Object> T
      firstOrDefault(List<T> list, T defaultValue)`. T is non-null if defaultValue is non-null too. https://jspecify.dev/user-guide.html#using-type-variables-in-generic-methods

Comment: The current version of JSpecify today (0.2.0) does support the `firstOrDefault` case, but the original poster is looking for something a little different: The original poster wants something like [the Checker Framework `@PolyNull`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/PolyNull.html). (That won't help if you use FindBugs, but it will help if you use the Checker Framework.) Someday JSpecify may attempt to [add a feature like `@PolyNull`](https://github.com/jspecify/jspecify/issues/79), depending in part on whether it can be implemented by many tools.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out a solution yet. The toughest part about implementing it is getting across that the method return value inherits *not* the nullability annotation of the `text` parameter but of the *argument value* passed to it, in this case that of `trimmedOrEmptyIfNull`. Here are some ideas:

- Add a new parameter annotation to use in place of the existing annotation. This isn't clear that it applies to the method's return value, nor does it make checking the body of the method easy. Do you assume the parameter is marked `@CheckForNull`?

  ```
  public static String truncate(@InheritNullness text, int maxLength) { ... }
  ```
- Add a parameter to a new method annotation. This also isn't clear that the nullability of the argument passed by the calling code is what is inherited.

  ```
  @Nullability(inherit = "text")
  public static String truncate(@CheckForNull text, int maxLength) { ... }
  ```
- Since 99% of the cases will probably involve overriding a `@CheckForNull` or `@Nullable` annotation with `@Nonnull` (is that a reasonable assumption?), add a new parameter annotation to use in addition to the existing annotation. This isn't clear that it applies to the method's return value, nor does it make checking the body of the method easy. Do you assume the parameter is marked `@CheckForNull`?

  ```
  @CheckForNull
  public static String truncate(@InheritNonnull text, int maxLength) { ... }
  ```

I must admit I'm not really fond of any of them. :(